# Auto width for Listview UWP (Set width of widest row to all other rows)

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, uwp

I have a listview like this

```
<ListView Name="lview" Background="Aqua" ></ListView>
```

Code behind

```
        public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        var lv = new List<string>
        {
            "1", "22", "33", "444", "999999999"
        };
        lview.ItemsSource = lv;

    }
```

When I render this Listview I want it to take the width of the widest element, that is `999999999` here. how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > When I render this Listview I want it to take the width of the widest element.

You can set the **HorizontalAlignment** property of ListView as **Left** to fit the width. In this case, the width of ListView will equal to the width of the widest item.

.xaml:

```
<ListView Name="lview" Background="Aqua" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
</ListView>
```